# See change log of online Json

Tags: json, bash, wget, tail

I have a json online (6,5m) with nearly 10.000 geographic point. I'm looking for something to check changes. Nearly 60 points are added every day.

I found this : [tail -f equivalent for an URL](https://superuser.com/questions/514066/tail-f-equivalent-for-an-url)

But I have bash error on my debian when I try to using the command given.

At the end I would like to format them and send them to an irc channel.

Comment: 1. Download the current JSON to a timestamped file `data-20131129.json`. using `curl` or  `wget` 2. Diff it with the previous version `diff -u data-20131128.json data-20131129.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would safe the JSON file locally and diff it.

```
#!/bin/sh

# filename for current version of JSON file
d=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
current=data-$d.json # => data-20131129-123856.json

# download current version of JSON file
wget --quiet -O $current http://www.lhorn.de/~lutz/so/data.json

# determine the previous version of the JSON file (the second to last)
previous=$(find . -name "data-*.json" | sort | tail -2 | head -1)

# diff the previous and the current version of the JSON file
diff -u $previous $current
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will edit it a little bit to avoid too many data-$d.json otherwise i will quickly kill my raspberry.

Comment: I've added `ls -t -C1 data-201* | awk 'NR>1' | xargs rm` at the begining